# How to understand CV

Tags: machine-learning-model, cross-validation

How to interpret cross_validation score in that case? While cross-val equeals minus
[image]

Comment: No idea: it's the average of some performance metric, but the metric depends on the system and/or parameters you're using.

Comment: Which metric are you using for "scoring" in cross_val_score? Sharing the code on how you are calculating "Cross Val" will help you to get answers...